# Change the background colour of a Delphi TGrid (FireMonkey) based on value in another column

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to figure out how to change the background colour on a Delphi TGrid (FMX) based upon a value in another column which is contained in the dataset. Obviously there is the "DrawColumnBackground" event for this purpose, but I cannot figure out how to access another value in the grid/dataset to determine what colour to render. I've attached a picture showing the "RowMod" column which should be used to determine the background colour instead of the alternate bg colour being used.

```
procedure GridDrawColumnBackground(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn;
  const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
var
  OldKind: TBrushKind;
  OldColor: TAlphaColor;
begin
  if [Get-RowMod-Value] = 1 then  // <-- How to get this cell value?
  begin
    OldKind := Canvas.Fill.Kind;
    OldColor := Canvas.Fill.Color;

    Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Yellow;
    Canvas.Fill.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, AllCorners, 1);

    Canvas.Fill.Color := OldColor;
    Canvas.Fill.Kind := OldKind;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Deosn't the DataSet just follow along with the grid, ie. if you access the dataset (using _FieldByName('FieldName').AsInteger_) you get the value for the current row?

Comment: It doesn't in FireMonkey with LiveBindings. The grid seems to entirely disconnected from the dataset at the point of drawing cells.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up switching to a TStringGrid with a DrawColumnCell event as shown below. Wasn't any easy way to do otherwise, so will have to deal with the cell drawing manually which will provide greater flexibility at the expense of some nitty gritty coding.

```
procedure StringGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Canvas: TCanvas;
  const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF; const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
const
  EvenColor: TAlphaColor = $20FFFFFF;
  OddColor: TAlphaColor = $20000000;
var
  R: TRectF;
begin
  // Draw the cell background
  if StringGrid1.Cells[2, Row] = '1' then
    Canvas.Fill.Color := OddColor
  else
    Canvas.Fill.Color := EvenColor;
  R := Bounds;
  R.Inflate(3, 3);
  Canvas.FillRect(R, 0, 0, AllCorners, 1.0);

  // Draw the cell text
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
  Canvas.FillText(Bounds, Value.AsString, False, 1, [], TTextAlign.Leading, TTextAlign.Center);
end;
```

Resulting grid works as desired as shown below. To achieve the selected row highlighting requires setting the Alpha transparency in the TAlphaColor, which I've set to 32 (#20 or $20 as first 2 bit of the hex code).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This case will highlight something unexpected: TGrid does not store data values ​​but rather a display of data!

On holidays, I will not explain how to do but give you a link
[Grid And Livebindings (in french)](https://serge-girard.developpez.com/tutoriels/Delphi/Livebindings/Grilles/#LVI-B-3)
where I explain how to override this